# Oracle 12 XMLElement: no tag if value_expr is null

Tags: oracle, xmlelement

A good morning from Germany.

Now, is there a way to suppress the whole tag in an XMLElement if the value_expr is null?

Like: suppress the "bingo" tag:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT( "artno", trim(artno) )
     , XMLELEMENT( "bingo", NULL )
  FROM articlemasterdata
 WHERE artno = '770100C'

<artnr>770100C</artnr>
<bingo></bingo>
```

Even XMLTYPE delivers an empty tag:

```
SELECT XMLTYPE( XMLELEMENT( "artno", trim(artno) ).getclobval() ) 
    ,  XMLTYPE( XMLELEMENT( "bingo", null ).getclobval() )
  FROM articlemasterdata 
 WHERE artno = '770100C';

<artnr>770100C</artnr>
<bingo></bingo>
```

Thank you,

Joachim

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xmlforest` instead of `xmlelement`:

```
-- CTE for dummy table
with articlemasterdata (artno) as (select '770100C' from dual)
-- actual query
SELECT XMLELEMENT( "artno", trim(artno) )
     , XMLFOREST(NULL as "bingo")
  FROM articlemasterdata
 WHERE artno = '770100C';

XMLELEMENT("ARTNO",TRIM(ARTNO))                                                  XMLFOREST(NULLAS"BINGO")                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<artno>770100C</artno>
```

Or perhaps slightly more realistically:

```
-- CTE for dummy table
with articlemasterdata (artno, bingo) as (
  select '770100A', 'legs eleven' from dual
  union all
  select '770100C', null from dual
)
-- actual query
SELECT XMLELEMENT( "artno", trim(artno) )
     , XMLFOREST( bingo as "bingo")
  FROM articlemasterdata
 WHERE artno = '770100A'
    OR artno = '770100C';

XMLELEMENT("ARTNO",TRIM(ARTNO))                                                  XMLFOREST(BINGOAS"BINGO")                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<artno>770100A</artno>                                                           <bingo>legs eleven</bingo>                                                      
<artno>770100C</artno>
```

or even:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT( "root",
         XMLELEMENT( "artno", trim(artno) )
       , XMLFOREST( bingo as "bingo")
       )
  FROM articlemasterdata
 WHERE artno = '770100A'
    OR artno = '770100C';

XMLELEMENT("ROOT",XMLELEMENT("ARTNO",TRIM(ARTNO)),XMLFOREST(BINGOAS"BINGO"))    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<root><artno>770100A</artno><bingo>legs eleven</bingo></root>
<root><artno>770100C</artno></root>
```